# Prevent Stage Skipping But Allow Regression

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I'd like to prevent users from "skipping" Opportunity Stages, but not from reverting the Stage back. For example, I do not want a user to advance to Stage 5 without having been in Stage 4 immediately prior. However, I want a user in Stages 6 or 7 to be able to revert back to Stage 5.

I have written the below Validation Rule, and would love any advice. Thank you.

```
OR( 

AND( 
NOT(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "1 - Plan"), 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "2 - Qualify")), 

AND( 
NOT(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "2 - Qualify"), 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "3 - Develop")))
```

Comment: Do you have Probabilities assigned to these Stages? A numeric field would be a lot easier to manage than building this formula out to handle all possible cases.

Comment: We change our probability %s or will shortly, and I'd like to stay away from using that as leverage point for a formula related to Stage progression. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we are using:

```
`(ABS(
/* By taking away 'ABS' from line above to look '((' you can allow regression to any stage */
CASE( Stage__c , 
"Stage 1",1, 
"Stage 2",2, 
"Stage 3",3, 
"Stage 4",4, 
"Stage 5",5, 
6) 
- 
CASE(PRIORVALUE(Stage__c ), 
"Stage 1",1, 
"Stage 2",2, 
"Stage 3",3, 
"Stage 4",4, 
"Stage 5",5,
6) 
) * 
/* 'Stage 0' or 'Rejected' can be set from any */
CASE( Stage__c , 
"Stage 0",0, 
"Rejected",0, 
1) 
> 1) 
/* Custom settings (hierarchical) allow to bypass this validation for User or Role identified as admin or one, not triggering validations */
&& !$Setup.app_Logic__c.RunAs_Admin__c 
&& $Setup.app_Logic__c.Run_Validation_Rules__c`
```

Comment: It looks like you can only go backwards one stage at a time, though (because of the ABS). Still, that could easily be changed if they wanted regression to any lower stage.

Comment: This would still allow to go to Stage 5 from Stage 6 or 7 )). Taking away ABS would allow regression to any stage, as any regression would produce a negative number

Comment: They want to allow any amount of regression. If they were in stage 5 and went back to stage 3, this validation rule stop them unless they first went through stage 4.

Comment: I added a comment below 1st line of the code with instructions,

Comment: This is too complex for our StageName field. We have the following Stage Names:

1 - Plan
2 - Qualify
3 - Develop
4 - Propose
5 - Negotiate
6 - Contract
7 - Closing
Closed Won
Closed Lost

Comment: There is nothing complex in it: `(
CASE( StageName, 
"Plan",1, 
"Qualify",2, 
"Develop",3, 
"Propose",4, 
"Negotiate",5,
"Contract", 6,
"Closed Won", 7,
0) 
- 
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName ), 
"Plan",1, 
"Qualify",2, 
"Develop",3, 
"Propose",4, 
"Negotiate",5,
"Contract", 6,
"Closed Won", 7,
0) 
)
> 1`

Comment: I am unable to understand what your formula does, as it doesn't follow our StageNames, as I've listed them below. They are, `1 - Plan,
2 - Qualify,
3 - Develop,
4 - Propose,
5 - Negotiate,
6 - Contract,
7 - Closing`

Comment: Replace `Closed Won` I have in the formula with `Closing` and use it in the validation rule for `Opportunity`. It compares prior Stage value with current and allows stage progression by only one at a time, but can regress to any. You could have an error message like "Stages can not be skipped! Please select the next value from the picklist."

Comment: You mean this formula? `( CASE( StageName, "Plan",1, "Qualify",2, "Develop",3, "Propose",4, "Negotiate",5, "Contract", 6, "Closed Won", 7, 0) - CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName ), "Plan",1, "Qualify",2, "Develop",3, "Propose",4, "Negotiate",5, "Contract", 6, "Closed Won", 7, 0) ) > 1` or the above that your organization is using?

Comment: Yes, you can you this formula - it does what you were asking. I'm just not sure if you want to only allow to revert from Stage 6 and 7 to 5 (`I want a user in Stages 6 or 7 to be able to revert back to Stage 5`) or revert from any to any (this is what this formula allows)

Answer (score 1):

As a validation rule, if you're prefixing your stages, as in your example (`1 - Plan`, `2 - Qualify`, etc), you can parse this out and compare the values:

```
(VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(StageName), 1)) - VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName)), 1))) > 1
```

This lets you determine the appropriate order using the stage name directly. If you have more than 10 stages, you'll want adjust this formula appropriately.

---

If your users are primarily GUI users (you're not doing any manipulations through the API), you can use record types to achieve your goals. This eliminates the need for a validation rule, and the user won't be given error messages for doing things they shouldn't be doing.

Here's how it works:

## Part A: Sales Processes

Create multiple sales processes, each one represents a single phase in the process.

### Sales Process: Stage 1

Closed/Lost

Stage 1

Stage 2

### Sales Process: Stage 2

Closed/Lost

Stage 1

Stage 2

Stage 3

### Sales Process: Stage 3

Closed/Lost

Stage 1

Stage 2

Stage 3

Stage 4

...

## Part B: Record Types

Create new record types, one for each stage.

### Record Type: Stage 1

Sales Process: Stage 1

### Record Type: Stage 2

Sales Process: Stage 2

### Record Type: Stage 3

Sales Process: Stage 3

### Record Type: Stage 4

Sales Process: Stage 4

...

**NOTE**: Assign only the Stage 1 Record Type to profiles, and assign it as the default. Don't allow users to change the record type manually, as we'll take care of it for them.

## Part C: Workflow Rules

Finally, create workflow rules that change the record type accordingly:

### Workflow: Stage 1

When Stage Name equals Stage 1, set Record Type to Stage 1.

### Workflow: Stage 2

When Stage Name equals Stage 2, set Record Type to Stage 2.

### Workflow: Stage 3

When Stage Name equals Stage 3, set Record Type to Stage 3.

### Workflow: Stage 4

When Stage Name equals Stage 4, set Record Type to Stage 4.

...

---

The beauty of this configuration is that you can introduce new required fields at each stage, entirely alter page layouts, change the available picklist options, and so on. This behavior is completely transparent to users, will not generate error messages, and enforce the desired behavior. Of course, the downside is that this requires significantly more work to set up initially.

Comment: This will definitely not work, as we cannot make new record types, due to custom code dependencies, which are many.

Comment: @TamimJ What about the validation rule I proposed at the top?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of approaching this. If you have probabilities assigned, you can use the them, since with numeric fields this is much easier to handle. If not, it requires more effort.

Essentially, you wind up requiring that If ISCHANGED the PRIORVALUE has to be 1 value below the current one or can be any of the available values below the PRIORVALUE. One way of doing this is by using the CASE function with a different CASE for each Stage.

Using CASE expressions, it would look something like:

```
ISCHANGED(StageName)
AND(
CASE(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Stage 1"), 
TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 2",TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 3",TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 4"),
OR(    
CASE(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Stage 2"), 
    TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 1", TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 2",TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 3",TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 4")),
OR(    
CASE(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Stage 3"), 
    TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 2",TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 4")),
OR(
CASE(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Stage 4), 
    TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))= "Stage 3")))
```

Comment: Does this actually allow for regression? I don't see how but perhaps I need to read more carefully. Probability is good though, a clever combination of `OR` and `PRIORVALUE` ought to do the trick. Also your `ISCHANGED` is in the wrong spot.

Comment: Yes it does. It checks the current Stage and then runs the CASE for that stage. Ooops, let me correct. (blushes). I need to edit it. I've started with the prior value rather than the current value. It should allow the prior value to be 1 stage below the current stage or any other value above it, at least that's what I intended.

Comment: We change our probability %s or will shortly, and I'd like to stay away from using that as leverage point for a formula related to Stage progression. Thank you, though.

Comment: The above just uses the name and isn't intended to work with percentage values. It would actually be easier to do the latter which quite honestly wouldn't be dependent on whether you changed your stage percentage values or not.