# Prevent users from Skipping Stages Salesforce - Validation Rule

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I am trying to make a validation rule that does not allow Stage Skipping on the Opportunity Stage.
We don't work with certain names we just need to make sure that the previous stage is not skipped.

I read [this case](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116418/prevent-stage-skipping-but-allow-regression)  but it's for only certain stages like Stage 1 and Stage 2 but we don't have those numbers that we can take and minus text from left or right to determine the previous state.

I also read this [thread](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7rYRSAZ) but it's only for not allowing to reassign older stage.
How would I go about doing this with the 'CASE' statement to stop users tp skip stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach you stated in your question. In your case it would be something like this.

```
ISCHANGED(StageName) && (
CASE( StageName, 
"Stage 1",1, 
"Stage 2",2, 
"Stage 3",3, 
"Stage 4",4, 
"Stage 5",5, 
6) 
- 
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName), 
"Stage 1",1, 
"Stage 2",2, 
"Stage 3",3, 
"Stage 4",4, 
"Stage 5",5,
6) <> -1)
```

This will prevent the user from changing stage to any other stage then the next one.

the final comparison where it says <>-1, its supposed to be 1 and I also used ABS and allow users to go back and forth one stage at a time.
If you would like to have this ability restricted in your org please use the code below :

```
ISCHANGED(StageName) && ABS ( (
CASE( StageName, 
"Stage 1",1, 
"Stage 2",2, 
"Stage 3",3, 
"Stage 4",4, 
"Stage 5",5, 
6) 
- 
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName), 
"Stage 1",1, 
"Stage 2",2, 
"Stage 3",3, 
"Stage 4",4, 
"Stage 5",5,
6)) <>1)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, Just a question why is case 6 empty? is it looking for an empty stage?

Comment: The last item is a default value, if the stage name does not match any of the listed option it will go with the default one.

Comment: Hey so it either 1, it returns 1 when it's moving in the right direction, when I want to go backward I get -1, how would I go about saying it <>1 or -1 ? I want the values from substracting to be 1 or -1 nothing else

Comment: abs() around the whole left side and change the -1 to 1